# Getting taggable id of a logged user by facebook id

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In facebook graph api 2.0+ I can retrieve logged user friends list by calling "me/taggable_friends" and I receive list of objects with profile picture, name, and id (lets call it "taggable_id") which can be used in mentioning performed by my app.

When user logs to my app have his real facebook id which is "worth" more then "taggable_id" so is it possible to retrieve taggable_id of a logged user with the use of facebook id? When I call "/me/" I don't receive on. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible. Not in any way.